# ManyToManyField is being filtered excluded when passed through DRF view and serializer

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

When attempting to persist a new record to the database via POSTing through a Django Rest Framework route, my `ManyToManyField` named `shared_users` on the object is filtered out. It is weird as the new object is still created, however, the `shared_users` attribute appears as an empty list.

When I inspect via Python Debugger, everything is originally available on the request object.

```
(Pdb) request.data
<QueryDict: {u'shared_users[]': [u'4', u'5', u'1'], u'model_name': [u'A name'], u'description': [u'A description']}>
```

But when I inspect the field with `request.data.get('shared_users[]', [])` (not sure why fieldname appears with `[]` in the name), I get a result of `u'1'` (already missing two user id's).

And when I evaluate `serializer.data` it returns everything with expected values but the `shared_users` field, as below.

`{'last_modified_by': 3, 'description': u'A description', 'user': 3, 'shared_users': [], 'model_name': u'A name'}`

I have provided my views and serializers files for reference.

---

views.py

```
class MyCreateView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    pass
    serializer_class = MyCreateAndUpdateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('user'))

    def post(self, request, format=None, **kwargs):
        # This dictionary is used to ensure that the last_modified_by field is always updated on post to be the current user
        request_data = {
            'user': request.user.id,
            'model_name': request.data['model_name'],
            'description': request.data['description'],
            'last_modified_by': request.user.id,
            'shared_users': request.data.get('shared_users', [])
         }

    serializer = MyCreateAndUpdateSerializer(data=request_data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py

```
class MyCreateAndUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    shared_users = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=User.objects.all(), read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
          'pk',
          'user',
          'data',
          'model_name',
          'description',
          'created_at',
          'date_modified',
          'shared_users',
          'last_modified_by'
        ]
```

Comment: If your request parameter is `shared_users[]` and it passes in a list you should fetch it using `request.data.get_list('shared_users[]', [])`.

Comment: The [] in the parameter name comes from your HTML form or whoever is sending you the data. It’s a (silly?) PHP convention to name form parameters with multiple values like this. Django uses a QueryDict which accepts multiple values per parameter (and uses get_list to fetch them which is why all values of request.data are lists).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @dirkgroten for the answer to this.

Turns out the problem was `'shared_users': request.data.get('shared_users', [])` on the request_data dictonary in `views.py`. Because the value associated with `'shared_users[]'` is a list, I should have been using `getlist` to access the list e.g. `request.data.getlist('shared_users[]', [])`.

See [Django QueryDict Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict)